# Do journals that published a proof of an important theorem $T$ publish another proof of $T$?

Tags: soft-question, publishing

I want to know whether or not a journal that published a proof $P$ of an important theorem $T$ is still open to accept another proof $P'$ of $T$ such that $P'$ is greatly simpler than $P$, assuming, of course, that $P'$ is correct.

Comment: Sure, why not? It would depend on how important $T$ was and how much better or how illuminating the new proof was. I don't see why it would matter whether the old proof was published in the same journal or some other journal.

Comment: Do you have a simple proof of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Comment: @bof: Thanks for your attention. I am just being wary and discreet about choosing a journal. I have a simple proof of another of Fermat's theorem. We will see!

Comment: It's less about $T$ than about $P'$, you might say: A substantially new proof may use different (new?) methods, from which we can possibly learn more than from $T$ itself. Also, $P'$ may be so differnt that it may suggest different generalizations of $T$. You might even publish a new(!) proof of Pythagoras, adding to an already long collection.

Comment: @bof: So did you imply that if $T$ is a conjecture then situation is different?

Comment: How did I imply that? I thought we were talking about where to submit a new proof of a theorem which already has a proof. In my opinion (as a random anonymous internet loon), it makes sense to submit to the same journal that published the old proof. Assuming it wasn't too long ago, you at least know that the editors have some interest and knowledge of the subject of your theorem. Typically editors have to go through a trial and error process to find a suitable referee; in this case, they can use the same referees (or the author) of the old proof.

Comment: @bof:  Appreciated. I am just wondering why Fermat's last theorem is your first guess rather than Goldbach conjecture or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on many things. First of all, what is the relevance of $T$ in its field? And secondly: what is the relevance of the new proof of $T$?

In my field of research, nonlinear PDEs, it frequently happens that a researcher can solve a PDE by a "new" approach. However, this approach might be confined to that particular equation, and a referee may decide that the publication of a paper with a new proof that applies to a single problem is not worth.

But it also happens that a researcher introduces a new *method* that can be used to prove (hopefully in an easier way) some known result. If this method is fairly general and can be applied to other problems, then a referee will probably accept the manuscript for publication.

Finally, more and more journals recommend to their referees that manuscripts should be *original*. A different proof of theorem $T$ will then be rejected almost immediately is the manuscript is written only to show that you found another proof.